# Right way to evaluate sbt task from a simple method

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a task which, depends on other settings, should determine whether deploy my project to the production server or not, basically i'm call `publish` if everything is ok. But as i understand if pass publish task as a dependency or call `.value` on it, it's gonna be evaluated before the `deploy` task which is wrong. So i have to somehow run publish later from my method, i have the following structure:

```
val deploy: Initialize[...] = (...) map { (...) =>

  def innerMethod() = { ... } // <- here i need run publish

}
```

The only way i know of is:

```
EvaluateTask(struct, publish in Deploy, state, projRef)
```

It works, but i need to depend on `buildStructure`, `stats`, `thisProjectRef` settings, which i don't like. There is also a method on task `.evaluate` which expects some `Setting[Scope]` and where to get this. Are there any other ways to achive the similar logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered making it a command instead of a task? http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html

Settings may only depend on other settings; tasks may only depend on settings and other tasks; commands, however, can do whatever they want, basically. They're top-level constructs. A setting or task can't depend on a command, so you can't just use commands for everything, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is a top-level kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but publish is a simple Task[Unit] not a command. And my code works, i just don't like this dependecies

Comment: A command can invoke a task, so I'm not sure why you think "publish is a simple Task[Unit] not a command" counts as an objection?

Comment: Also, at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/h43T1xGlz4U Mark Harrah says "You only want to use evaluateTask from a Command" — it's not intended for use in tasks. The sbt documentation says so too: "not from another task" (http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Build-State.html)

Comment: I see, i guess i need to read a bit more. My actual logic is simple, i have a task `deploy` which looks if there were any changes in the project and if so, `publish` project to production if not just completes, if i pass `publish` as a dependency (in the applicative style of through `. value macro) it would be executed before any computation in `deploy`, so i need to defer this somehow.

Comment: Yes. I understand. You need to change your task into a command.